# Override Standard Documents Home Tab/Document Detail Page

Tags: apex, page-layout, button-overrides, document, page-override

### Is it possible to override the Documents home tab or Document detail page's buttons, links, and actions or page layout?

Salesforce describes how to override standard buttons and tabs [here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=links_customize_override.htm), but this only applies for the standard objects which are listed under **Setup | Customize** (e.g. Accounts, Leads, Contacts). Is it possible to do the same with Documents? Even if there is no way to override specific buttons/links on the page, is it possible to edit the Document Home Tab/Document detail page layout to include a Javascript override as described in [this StackExchange answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/75787/override-view-with-url)? I want to be able to replace the existing button actions with custom Apex methods.